# Creating equidistant points along polyline with multiple objects

Tags: qgis, point, line, point-creation

I want to create equidistant points along a polyline layer that consists of multiple objects. The problem using the "point along geometry" tool in the QGIS processing toolbox is that every object of that layer is seen as an independent line, so the algorithm starts again at every new object. This results in not equidistant points along the polyline layer.

Is there a way to ignore the objects of the polyline layer? I would like to avoid to merge the objects so that its information are kept.

Comment: What is wrong with merging the lines and creating points along the merged lines? It's not like you'll destroy the original data.

Comment: Make a copy of the layer for merging.

Comment: @Erik: You do destroy the data. Its not about multiple layers that are merged, its about on singe polyline layer consisting of multiple lines that make up one continous line. merging these objects of this polyline will create a polyline with one object and data is lost.

Comment: The original data will still be there, so it's not destroyed. You can later join relevant attributes by location back to the points.